# Set-Culture to set NumberDecimalSeparator

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to change Number Decimal Separator for the current user via powershell, in a permanent way; the machine is a Window 10 professional so it has the Set-Culture cmdlet out of the box.

I tryed this, but doesn't work:

```
$culture=Get-Culture

$culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator="."
$culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator=" "
$culture.NumberFormat.NumberNegativePattern=1

Set-Culture $culture
```

It doesn't return any exception but the settings aren't there.
I executed it as administrator.

Comment: the `Set-Culture` docs seem to imply that it ONLY sets the culture to noe of the predefined cultures. i am not certain of that, tho. [*blush*]

Comment: that's what I think too; how to set the 'sub' parts then?

Comment: I think the cultures are just templates, to change an individual users settings stick to the registry  `Get-Item 'hkcu:\Control Panel\International'`

Comment: @AgostinoX - i agree with what LotPings mentioned. [*sigh ...*] since the properties and methods all appear to be `get` with no matching `set`, it seems likely you will need to either go directly to the registry entries OR learn what other ways to do it exist - similar to how `cacls.exe/icacls.exe` can do permissions.

Comment: Set-Culture also doesn't really work how you'd expect unless oyu want to run a script every time they log in. If you want to try and set it permaenetly for a user then it's best to use group policy or amend the corresponding registry values e.g [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International]
"sDecimal"="."

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, `Set-Culture` only accepts *predefined* cultures, and **the only way to persistently *modify* a culture is to employ a *user override* of the user's current culture settings via the registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International`**:

```
@{ Name = 'sDecimal';   Value = '.' },
@{ Name = 'sThousand';  Value = ' ' },
@{ Name = 'iNegNumber'; Value = 1   } | 
  ForEach-Object {
    Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Control Panel\International' @_
  }
```

This is the equivalent of what you attempted in the question.
The changes will take effect in *future* PowerShell sessions.

Note that **you may also want to change the analogous settings for *currency* values**, via values `sMonDecialSep`, `sMonThousandSep`, and `iNegCurr`.

**Note:**

- Since the relevant registry value names may not be obvious, you can use Control Panel (`intl.cpl`) to change settings interactively, and then observe the effects on the values in the registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International` (via `regedit.exe`).
- If you later switch to a *different* culture, including via `Set-Culture`, your custom overrides are *discarded*.